# Why does the order of an if/elseif statement matter in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Why does the following code work:

```
@if (Auth::guest())
@elseif(Auth::user())
    <p>test</p>
@endif
```

and the following DOES NOT work?

```
@if(Auth::user())
    <p>test</p>
@elseif (Auth::guest())
@endif
```

It's the same logic, isn't it?

Comment: how do you define *does work* and *does not work*? What's really happening?

Comment: @Wreigh The first case prints "test" but the second doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

If your `if` the condition is getting satisfied then the PHP will not bother executing the `else` or `elseif` statement.

For an example

```
$flag = true;

if ($flag) {
  echo "true";
} elseif($flag) {
  echo "true inside flag";
}
```

This will echo out **true** Even if the condition inside `elseif` is also true, it will not get executed.